# Time which follows the mouse

Tags: javascript, time, mouseover

I just wrote a simple javascript which displays the time. So i asked myself if is it possible to display the time always over the mouse. I simply don´t know how to do it, I need your help.

Here is the JS Code

> function showTime() {
>
> ```
>         var currentTime = new Date();
>         var h = currentTime.getHours();
>         var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
>         var s = currentTime.getSeconds();
>
>         var myClock = document.getElementById('diClock');
>         myClock.textContent = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
>         requestAnimationFrame(showTime); }
> ```
>
> showTime();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a `mousemove` handler to the document, where you update the (absolute) position of `diClock` element to reflect the mouse coordinates you get from the event. The position update part and the time update part are separate; you do not need to change your `showTime` function.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don´t understand what you mean with "attach". diClock is an ID in a div. Could you please show it to me in the code ? 

http://jsfiddle.net/r54NJ/2/